# In vscode debug mode, enter the subfolder of the root directory of the workspace?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

My execution file is in a subfolder under the root directory of the workspace. How can I enter the corresponding subfolder instead of automatically entering the root directory of the workspace in debug mode?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) `${relativeFileDirname}` in your launch config